# span moves one to right in firefox

Tags: php, css, html

So I am working on a project to make portfolio page.
The idea of the site is that PHP counts how many files are in thumbs folder, then it prints them out and applies gallery image viewing add-on. At this moment it's working kinda flawless in chrome, but in Firefox my span elements are moving one to the right. Here's my PHP
Here's my php

```
<HTML>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tyyli.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/magnific-popup.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="yla">
                <div class="ylavasen"></div>
                <div class="ylakeski"><img class="logo" align="middle"  src="logo.png"></img></div>
                <div class="ylaoikea"><div class="cont" ><a href="mailto:i dont even know"><p class="contact">Contact Us</p></a></div></div>
            </div>

            <?php 
            // integer starts at 0 before counting
            $i = 0; 
            $dir = 'tumbit/';

            if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
                while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
                    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
                        $i++;
                }
            } //so this counts files
            ?> 

            <div class="popup-gallery">
                <?php 
                do {
                    echo '<a href="kuvat/kuva_'. $i .'.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_'. $i.'.png"></a>'; //and this echo's them to the page.
                    $i = $i - 1;
                } while ($i>0);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">Some random footer ;D</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

I know it's not kinda pretty and stuff, but it is what it is. 
Oh, and for those who don't have server etc, here comes output html:

```
<HTML>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tyyli.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/magnific-popup.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="yla">
                <div class="ylavasen"></div>
                <div class="ylakeski"><img class="logo" align="middle"  src="logo.png"></img></div>
                <div class="ylaoikea"><div class="cont" ><a href="mailto:asd"><p class="contact">Contact Us</p></a></div></div>
            </div>

            <div class="popup-gallery">
                <a href="kuvat/kuva_11.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_11.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_10.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_10.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_9.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_9.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_8.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_8.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_7.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_7.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_6.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_6.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_5.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_5.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_4.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_4.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_3.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_3.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_2.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_2.png"></a><a href="kuvat/kuva_1.jpg" class="homo"><span class="huora">View</span><img class="huoran" src="tumbit/thumb_1.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">again, a random footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Here is my css:

```
body {
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
font-family:Verdana;
height:100%;
margin:0 0 0 0;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width:1200px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.yla {
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    text-align:center;
    height:145px;
    z-index:1;
    }
.ylavasen {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    }
.ylakeski {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    }
.ylaoikea {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    height:142;
    }
.cont {
    background-color:#ed1c24;
    height:26px;
    width:117px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:116px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:0px;
    }
.contact {
    color:white;
    font-family:Verdana;
    }
.cont:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}
.thumb {
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    z-index:1;  
    }
.thumb:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    }
.kuvat {
    text-align:center;
    }
a {
text-decoration:none
}
.popup-gallery {
    max-width:1200px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    min-height:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:no;
    clear:both;
    z-index:3;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    }
.footer {
    text-align:center;
    color:#b49980;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;   
    z-index:-2;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:-1;
    max-width:1200px;
    width:100%;
    }
.teksti {
    display:none;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    float:left;
    }
.homo {
    padding: 0;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
}
.huora {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.huora:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    background:black;
}
img.huoran {
    float:left;
}
```

Nothing is cool or clean in my code so sorry about that. 
Thanks already for your help

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "moving one to right"? one pixel? one span element's width? one inch?

Comment: One width of the element.

Comment: Could you provide us a screenshot? Because this html/css looks ok in my firefox.

Comment: image tags should be closed like this: `<img src="blah" />` you haven't closed some and you have closed others using `</img>`, other than that it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/eWWQN/1/

Comment: @Pete: WRONG! See http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_img.asp or others

Comment: @DonJuwe sorry, I always work to XHTML so I forgot that normal html doesn't need it but the </img> is still wrong

Comment: it is not necessary imo, but i like to do it, so i wont get my head spinning. Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, this may be your solution:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4xN4z/2/)

```
.homo {
    padding: 0;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.huora {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
img.huoran {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: If i'd be close to you, i would kiss you <3
And yea this fixed my issue, that i have been working for a day now...